# Not reachable accept state in DFA

Tags: computational-complexity, automata, regular-expressions

I am trying to show that every deterministic complete finite automaton that recognizes the language $a^*b+b^*$ for $\Sigma = \{a,b\}$ contains a state $q$ such that no accept state can be reached from q on a directed path.

I don't know how to present a diagram here so I use the following link to illustrate the DFA for 'what I think is a good diagram'.  [Here](https://cyberzhg.github.io/toolbox/nfa2dfa), I just think the diagram on this page lacks the consideration of an "empty" input so the initial node should be an accept state as well.

However, I am not sure what am I missing in order to prove the question above?
Any hints appreciated.

Comment: Where is the automaton after reading $ba$?  BTW, I can see no diagram at the link you posted.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To say that a DFA has such a state is to say that there exists a string $w$ such that no string $wx$ is accepted for any $x\in \Sigma^*$. So we need to find some string that is not the prefix of any accepted word.

Hint: $abb$ is such a string.

Comment: $ab$ is in the language.  You probably meant $ba$.

Comment: I guess I interpreted the question differently. I assumed that the directed path needs to be non-trivial. If so, then both $ab$ and $ba$ work. If you don’t make this assumption, then $ab$ no longer works.

Comment: Changed for clarity.

Comment: Thanks for clarifying.